# Why does one usb flash drive have different serial numbers in different operating systems?

Tags: kubuntu, windows-10, usb-drive

Why does *one* usb flash drive have *different* serial numbers in *different* operating systems?

Ubuntu:
**$ usb-devices**
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13fe ProdID=4100 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=
S:  Product=USB DISK 2.0
S:  **SerialNumber**=**070A3638B1831375**
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
...

Windows:
**>wmic diskdrive get Caption, InterfaceType, MediaType, SerialNumber**
Caption                           InterfaceType  MediaType              **SerialNumber**
USB DISK 2.0 USB Device           USB            Removable Media        **017307A53060**
...

Comment: That was a bad flash drive.  
Two of the three flash drives have equal serial numbers in Ubuntu and Windows.  
Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

- It is possible that one of the tools shows the serial number of the adapter, and the other tool shows serial number of the disk.

  I like `lsblk`. You find the output options via `lsblk --help` and `man lsblk`.
- Some tools seem to truncate or mix the information about model and serial number.

In Ubuntu there are several commands that show similar information, and you can run them yourself and check if some of them match between each other and with the Windows tool.

```
usb-devices | grep -iA2 manufacturer

LANG=C sudo parted -ls | grep -A1 Model:

lsblk -do name,model,serial

# and for each interesting device sdx

ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdb$  # e.g. for device sdb

sudo lshw|less  # and scroll down to find info about the device
```